# Conditionally choosing which function to call

Tags: functional-programming, elisp

Why doesn't the following work?

```
((if t + -) 1 1)
```

How can I get the `if` expression to resolve to provide the correct function?  I don't want to repeat myself, as in `(if t (+ 1 1) (- 1 1))`.

Comment: `(apply (if t '+ '-) '(1 1))`, *maybe*. I really don’t know Lisp. Especially not Emacs Lisp.

Comment: (This also works, so is a valid answer)

Answer (score 2):

Emacs Lisp is a Lisp-2, meaning it has a separate namespace for functions. To refer to a function as a value in Emacs Lisp, you need to quote it. And to call a function referenced in this way, you need to use `funcall`. So what you want is:

```
(funcall (if t '+ '-) 1 1)
```